# redirect from l.domain.com/TARGETID to domain.com/redirect?target=TARGETID

Tags: apache, .htaccess, subdomain

Can't figure out the .htaccess code for this one :/

If the subdomain "l" is used it should redirect like mentioned in the title

also in the browser the url should still be displayed as l.domain.com/TARGETID

Comment: *"also in the browser the url should still be displayed as l.domain.com/TARGETID"* then you **don't** want to redirect. Are both of these domains pointing to the same document root? are they on the same server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting this in the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^l\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/redirect
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /redirect?target=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: fix your typo at "/redirect=target=..." to "/redirect?target=..." . And your answer is perfect :)